# replacing a value in a mysql database with a reply from user in private message discord.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, discord.js

So, I have a bot asking a user some questions in a private chat after initiating the conversation in a public channel on a discord server. I wish to have the reply given by the user in the private chat to update a certain field in my mysql database.

```html
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
if(message.channel.id === '460633878244229120') return message.author.send(`Greetings, ${message.author.username}!

  FIRST QUESTION, **What is the name of your Brawler or Character?**`)
  .then((newmsg) => { //Now newmsg is the message you sent
    newmsg.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content, {
      max: 1,
      time: 10000,
      errors: ['time'],
    }).then((collected) => {
      newmsg.channel.send(`Your Name is: ${collected.first().content}`)
        var sql = (`UPDATE profile SET name = ${collected.first().content} WHERE id = ${newmsg.author.id}`);
    }).catch(() => {
      newmsg.channel.send('Please submit a name for your character. To restart Profile creation, please type "!profilecreate" command in Profile Creation channel on the server.');
    });
  });
}
```

Everything else works except the submitting the line into the database. It looks to not even attempt to run the line at all as I have not received a syntax error when I know there should have been. I am new to coding in general, let alone JS.

Comment: All you are doing is defining the variable sql and setting it to the sql query string. You will need to connect to the database and execute the query to actually save the name.

Comment: I have the database connected in a file for the bot, while the file with the code I displayed above is in a command file. So I need to connect the database in every file that uses the database in it, or because it is in the main bot file, I shouldn't need to? Are you saying I need to put the "bot.query . . ." section in this code as well? If so, that would make sense and I feel stupid for not thinking of that. XD